# I am try to interactively add a user via "useradd"

Tags: bash, ubuntu, useradd

I am basically trying to write a simple script to allow for interactive use of "useradd" with select options.

The options I am trying to allow for specific use are to either be defined interactively or set to the next available or default settings.

The main problem I am having is how to get the next available values to occur for value like group id and groups.

I imagine I can set preset values for the home directory and shell but I wanted to find out if there is a not so brute force method other than making constants for these variables.

Here is where I have made it to so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Script to add a user to Linux system

if [ $(id -u) -eq 0 ]; then
    read -p "Enter username : " username
    read -p "Enter password : " password
    read -p "Enter group id or [default to next available]: " gid
    read -p "Enter additional groups or [default to next available]: " group
    read -p "Enter home directory or [default to next available]: " hdir
    read -p "Enter desired shell or [default to next available]: " difshell

    egrep "^$username" /etc/passwd >/dev/null
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "$username exists!"
        exit 1
    else
        pass=$(perl -e 'print crypt($ARGV[0], "password")' $password)
        useradd -p$pass -g$gid -G$group -d$hdir -s$difshell $username
        [ $? -eq 0 ] && echo "User has been added to system!" || echo "Failed to add a user!"
    fi
else
    echo "Only root may add a user to the system"
    exit 2
fi
```

Comment: Which OS/distribution and version do you use?

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Comment: Tools like `useradd` will automatically determine the next available UID/GID if not explicitly provided. Why not use the features built into that tool instead of calculating it yourself?

Comment: Why not just use `adduser` ?

Comment: @Patrick I want the auto function as well as having the options of creating users with ease depending on where I need to put them and HAVE the options to change UID/GID. I will most likely just go on with the next auto number but I am trying to write a script that can have these additional options.

Comment: @wurtel I am basically trying to create a custom version of adduser that is MORE interactive. Like setting GID, Groups, and different shell. Simply running adduser doesn't do this. I can go back after and change these things latter of course but I am trying to have the options to do them interactively from the create point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you mean by "next available" with respect to the $HOME and $SHELL variables. Those you just set to their defaults: `/home/USERNAME` and `/bin/bash` or whatever. For the `$HOME`, just make sure the directory does not exist (`[ -e "/home/$username" ] && echo "Directory exists"`).

As for the groups, just list the available groups and take the next one. The [Debian policy on groups](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-opersys.html#s9.2.2) (and I believe this is not restricted to Debian) states that normal users should have GIDs between 1000 and 5999. So, all you need to do is parse `/etc/passwd`, print the existing groups in that range and then add one:

```
grp=$(awk -F: '$4>=1000 && $4<6000{print $4+1}' /etc/passwd | sort -n | tail -n1)
```

The `awk` command will print the value of the 4th `:`-separated field plus 1 if its value is between 1000 and 6000. This is then sorted and the lat line is kept. The result is a GID that is one greater than the current greatest one.

Comment: A big step in the right direction. Next avail for home directory and shell type was supposed to say default instead of next avail. I forgot to go back after the copy/paste. Thanks for the good direction to head in!

Comment: @user3347022 You're very welcome! The default shell can be `/bin/bash` and default home `/home/username` I don't see what else you would need.